# Gnuplot bad data on line 1

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Well, I am getting the error

```
    gnuplot> plot "plot_error.p"
                  ^
             Bad data on line 1
```

when trying to execute the plotting script `plot_error.p` on the following datafile (`tesc_error.dat`)

```
    2       0.02373300      0.00187922
    3       0.12182900      0.01080161
    4       0.30066000      0.02936487
    5       0.88415600      0.07882007
    6       1.70864800      0.14576794
    7       4.11814900      0.44127670
    8       8.79967900      0.84273207
    9       22.09179700     2.25049799
    10      54.13644000     5.28557289
    11      164.75478299    20.67593118
    12      376.32501997    39.98897077
    13      807.50995700    82.47956624
```

The script is

```
    set encoding iso_8859_1
    set terminal postscript eps enhanced color solid
    set xrange[1:14] 
    set yrange[0:900] 
    set title "1D MFPT" 
    set xlabel "{/Symbol G}" 
    set ylabel "t_{esc}" 
    unset key

    set output "tesc_error.eps" 

    y(x)=1/(9*x**(2/3))*exp(x-1)

    plot "tesc_error.dat" with yerrorbars, y(x) lt rgb "blue" 

    set key
```

The most weird thing is that I have recently plotted it without errors, but suddenly it pops that error. I've inspected line 1 of the datafile and nothing seems strange in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that you call a script with the `plot` command.
Try:

```
load "plot_error.p"
```

instead.
The `plot` command expects a data file and not a script.

Comment: Omg. Most noobish thing ever. I've being working too much for today I could not see it. Thank you.